# What Java classes/packages are automatically imported?

Tags: java, class, package

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!"); 
    }
}
```

In the above example we are using the `println` method without importing the package of it. So I want to know: What are the packages or classes included automatically?

Comment: `java.lang` package is automatically imported.

Comment: You should use an IDE, such as IntelliJ, which can do most of the `import` and package management for you automatically.

Answer (score 11):

**Everything** in [`java.lang`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html) is imported by default - here you are using [`java.lang.System`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) and [`java.lang.String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: Not quite everything... See the excerpt from JLS in my answer.

Comment: @AndyTurner Perhaps more specifically I should say the compiler implicitly imports everything in `java.lang` (agreed sub packages are not included).

Comment: @AndyTurner You're right, I misinterpreted your comment in the context of Elliot's reply.

Answer (score 8):

There are two packages imported by default:

- `java.lang`
- The package in which the current class is located (in the case of the above code, this is ostensibly the default package, from which you can't otherwise import explicitly).

From the [language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5):

> Code in a compilation unit automatically has access to all types declared in its package and also automatically imports all of the public types declared in the predefined package java.lang.

So, you only have access to **public** types in `java.lang`, but you have access to all top-level types in the current package.

But it's important to note that Java packages aren't hierarchical, despite the appearance, so this means that e.g. `java.lang.reflect` is not also imported automatically because of `java.lang` being imported.

Answer (score 0):

In every java class, `java.lang` is imported by default.

Apart from this, package (namely ***non-private*** classes of the package) you're having your class in, is also *available/visible* to your class, **unless** you have your class in a ***default package***, which is if you have your class without package definition.