# Confused about BootstrapClassLoader java.lang java.io

Tags: java, jvm

The BootstrapClassLoader loads `rt.jar` in memory, why `java.io` requires import but `java.lang` does not?

Comment: Which Java version are you referring to? Having `BootstrapClassLoader` and `rt.jar` in one environment sounds…very unusual. Further, looking into internals of the JDK will not answer your fundamental programming questions. You should [start here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is imported by default (i.e.implicitly). See [this other question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852375/what-java-classes-packages-are-automatically-imported). That's simply how the language works.

Comment: Thank you all the same,What I really want to know is what's the difference between loading into memory and importing?

Comment: That's not what you are asking, though. You might want to edit the question in that case. However, the difference is easy: when you import a package or class in one of your classes, you make it available in that class at development time (i.e. you can use it in your own code). When something is loaded into memory, it's available for your CPU to execute/access/etc.